# Css Chrome Firefox diff

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have next code which work differently in Chrome in Firefox. My questions is: What must should I add to fix firefox to work exact like Chrome?
Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aduew9uo/)
Screens: Screens: [Chrome](http://postimg.org/image/eii4vl5rn/) [Firefox](http://postimg.org/image/9pbkjzz9d/)

```
<table class="ui cellled striped table" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asddd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdda</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdddd</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and js:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
$( '#table tbody tr td' ).click(function() {
  $( "#table .ui.sticky" ).sticky('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Differently... *how*? Please clarify.

Comment: I wached them on both browsers, things look the same. Can you provide some screenshots or be more detailed, please?

Comment: I get them overlapping on both browsers, I would suggest that this is correct behaviour if you are adding `fixed top` class to all of them and not giving them any left to distinguish between them

Comment: Screens: [Chrome](http://postimg.org/image/eii4vl5rn/) [Firefox](http://postimg.org/image/9pbkjzz9d/)